# Cannot read property 'Chart' of undefined highcharts-ng

Tags: angularjs, highcharts-ng

Hello I have a problem with highcharts-ng
I put

```
angular.module('myApp', [...'highcharts-ng'])
```

In my **index.html**

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
```

In my **view.html**

```
<highchart id="chart1" config="chartOptions"></highchart>
```

And in **ctrl**

```
$scope.chartOptions= {
                options: {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'bar'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
                }],
                title: {
                    text: 'Hello'
                },

                loading: false
            }
```

That it's a default configuration on https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng
But it return error:

```
Cannot read property 'Chart' of undefined
    at initChart (vendors.min.js:41767)
    at linkWithHighcharts (vendors.min.js:41782)
    at highchartsCb (vendors.min.js:41896)
    at processQueue (vendors.min.js:16209)
    at vendors.min.js:16225
    at Scope.$eval (vendors.min.js:17483)
    at Scope.$digest (vendors.min.js:17296)
    at ChildScope.$apply (vendors.min.js:17591)
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (vendors.min.js:25666)
    at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (vendors.min.js:3)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The error suggests that when ng-highchart runs, it cannot find the global object Highcharts (see line 334 in https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/blob/master/dist/highcharts-ng.js). The reason for this is still unclear. Could you post all the scripts you're loading in your index and their order? Also: which version of highcharts-ng are you using?

Comment: In this moment it work, because I'm minifying all my js file ( with gulp ) in once, and so if I put the <script src..> out of minification it work but if I join highchartscript with others filejs, it return error.
maybe there is a Conflict but I don't know where and why...

Comment: When you concat JS, the order is very important. Make sure the highcharts.src.js is added before highcharts-ng.js. So for example if you use gulp.concat, make sure you don't just give it a glob like *.js, but instead put all files in appropriate order.